# I wanna achieve a functionality where as soon as a lead is converted,assign the Contact to the Account Contact Roles as the primary contact

Tags: trigger, opportunity, account, contact, lead-conversion

I have a requirement where I have to assign the Contact to the Account Contact Roles as the primary contact,whenever a lead is converted.

But I am not sure how it will be achieved?
If it is going to be achieved with the help of a trigger,then on what object should I use the trigger,since lead object gets destroyed after getting converted to Account,Contact & Opportunity.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Database.LeadConvert** for converted leads.So i share some code related to auto convert a lead when Lead status = webform. Customize based on your requirements.

```
trigger AutoConverter on Lead (after insert) {
 LeadStatus convertStatus = [
      select MasterLabel
      from LeadStatus
      where IsConverted = true
      limit 1
 ];
 List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

 for (Lead lead: Trigger.new) {
      if (!lead.isConverted && lead.WebForm__c == 'Free Trial') {
           Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
           String oppName = lead.Name;

           lc.setLeadId(lead.Id);
           lc.setOpportunityName(oppName);
           lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

           leadConverts.add(lc);
      }
 }

 if (!leadConverts.isEmpty()) {
      List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(leadConverts);
 }
```

}

If you face any issues let me know @Shobhit Saxena

Comment: -1, you clearly did not read the question. OP was not asking how to convert a lead programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for giving your suggestions @All.
Finally I got my task done.Following is the piece of code that worked for me:

```
trigger PopulateContactRoleOnConversion on Lead (before update) 
{
    PopulateContactRoleOnConversionHandler obj1=new PopulateContactRoleOnConversionHandler ();    //Creating an object of Handler class.
    obj1.onBeforeUpdate(trigger.new);    //Calling the Handler class method


}
```

The Handler class :

```
public with sharing class PopulateContactRoleOnConversionHandler 
{
    public void onBeforeUpdate(List<Lead> lstLeads)
    {
        Map<Id,String> leadAccountStatus = new Map<Id,String>(); // Map of the converted AccountID and the Lead Status
        //Map<Id,String> leadContactStatus = new Map<Id,String>(); // Map of the converted ContactID and the Lead Status
        for(Lead lead :lstLeads) 
        {
              if (lead.IsConverted)

              leadAccountStatus.put(lead.ConvertedAccountId,lead.Status);



        }
        List<Account> lstAccounts = [SELECT Id from Account WHERE Id IN :leadAccountStatus.keySet()];

        for ( Account acc : lstAccounts) 
        {
              Contact con=[SELECT Id,Phone,Email FROM Contact where Account.ID =:acc.ID];
              AccountContactRole objAccountContactRole=new AccountContactRole();
              objAccountContactRole.AccountId=acc.Id;
              objAccountContactRole.ContactId=con.Id;
              objAccountContactRole.Role='Business User';
              objAccountContactRole.isPrimary=true;
              insert objAccountContactRole;


        }
    }
}
```